# How to track event changes to a polygon with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I'm currently building a 'search an area' feature for a site we're working on. A bit like the one on [Rightmove](http://www.rightmove.co.uk/draw-a-search.html).

I've got everything up and running except the ability to track event changes to a polygon (the setting of new points and altering existing ones). I need to be able to post the coordinates to the form for submission.

I've tried the Google Code docs for [editing events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#user_editable_shapes_events). And every time I try it out, I either get a message about 'set_at' not being possible or my object not being defined.

I suppose the bit I know is wrong is `thePolygon` variable not being passed through to the new

```
google.maps.event.addListener(thePolygon, 'set_at', function() {
      // grab paths for infoWindow 
      grabPaths(thePath);
    });
```

But I don't know why. It's a global variable. Or is not?

**So, the question is, how can I track the changes to the polygon to pass the updated coordinates through to my form?**

All help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
var mapOptions = {
  // options
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
  drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
  drawingControl: false,
  polygonOptions: {
    // drawing options
  }
});

drawingManager.setMap(map);
  
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
  // complete functions
});

google.maps.event.addListener(thePolygon, 'set_at', function() {
  // complete functions
});

google.maps.event.addListener(thePolygon, 'insert_at', function() {
  // complete functions
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

these events are defined for MVCArray, a polyline is not a MVCArray.  You must observe the events for the `path` of the polyline(which is a MVCArray) instead. Furthermore you can't add a listener to an object that isn't created yet. The polygon is not available before `polygoncomplete`, so you must add the listeners inside the polygoncomplete-callback:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager,'polygoncomplete',function(polygon) {

  // complete functions

  google.maps.event.addListener(thePath, 'set_at', function() {
    // complete functions
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(thePath, 'insert_at', function() {
    // complete functions
  });

});
```

Comment: Ha ha,  works a treat. I was so close, yet so far. Thanks for your help. It was greatly appreciated. It was the grabbing the path changes that I couldn't fathom out. Yet it was so simple.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515748/event-after-modifying-polygon-in-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: use `polygon.getPath()` instead of `thePath`

Comment: This won't work for polygons with multiple paths. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789385/how-can-i-detect-when-an-editable-polygon-is-modified

Comment: How do I call class level functtion and variable inside set_at and insert_at event listeners?