# How can I detect when an editable polygon is modified?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3

How can I detect when an editable polygon is modified (point moved, point added, point removed) or dragged? The Google Maps API docs only list mouse [events for Polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[Polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) are made of Paths which are just [MVCArrays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray) (in this case, they're a list of LatLng objects). MVCArrays have three events: `insert_at`, `remove_at`, and `set_at`. We can use those events to detect changes in the points of the Polygon.

There are also [drag events for polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#dragging_events): `dragstart`, `drag`, and `dragend`. It's best to listen for `dragend` if you want to know that a shape was just dragged.

All together, we can detect any changes to a polygon:

```
// Loop through all paths in the polygon and add listeners
// to them. If we just used `getPath()` then we wouldn't 
// detect all changes to shapes like donuts.
polygon.getPaths().forEach(function(path, index){

  google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'insert_at', function(){
    // New point
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'remove_at', function(){
    // Point was removed
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'set_at', function(){
    // Point was moved
  });

});

google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'dragend', function(){
  // Polygon was dragged
});
```

Comment: Do we need to enable any property to drag the polygon ? By Default, I cant drag the polygon. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @ArunRaj `polygon.setDraggable(true);`

Comment: Thanks for this, will definitely be referring users to this usage

Comment: Is there any event to control user behavior where he/she can draw only single polygon? The `DrawingLibrary` has only `overlaycomplete` or `polygoncomplete` events. Any thoughts?